# Copying MYSQL database tables with Java – collation problems

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, collation

I know there are a lot of answers and tutorials about MYSQL and collation, but I still can't figure out where my problem is – sorry.

**what I want to do**
is copying a complete database from server **A** to server **B** (and some other stuff afterwards)

**how I do it**
I wrote a Java program that

- connects to server **A**
- retrieves the list of all tables in the database
- queries the "SHOW CREATE"-statement for each table
- connects to server **B**
- executes the "SHOW CREATE"-statement
- and then SELECTs and INSERTs the table rows from **A** into **B**

**the problem**
is that there is for example a table with a few thousand city names in their respective languages (english, german, french, swedish, russian ...). But after copying some of the names (especially russian cities) are unreadable. For example *Алханай* becomes *??????*
However special characters from other languages are kept correctly. Like the danish *ø* or german umlauts *äüö* – they all work, only russian is messed up afterwards

**what I tried**

- I rechecked the collation of every table in both databases and they are the same: **utf8_general_ci**
- initializing the JDBC-driver and set it to *use unicode* and the *character encoding* to *UTF-8*
- I even start the program with the option *-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8* (although I am not sure what this does)

If you have any more ideas, I'd appreciate it! thanks

**this is how I initialize the connection:**

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 Properties sqlInfo = new Properties();
 sqlInfo.setProperty("user", "myUser");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("password", "******");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("zeroDateTimeBehavior", "round");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("useCompression", "true");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
 sqlInfo.setProperty("collation_connection", "utf8_general_ci");
 Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://url/to/my/server:3306/myDbSchema", sqlInfo);
```

**and then I get the CREATE TABLE by executing a statement like this**

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW CREATE TABLE " + myTableName);
```

Comment: Why don't u use backup and restore feature?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set any of that charset/unicode stuff on the connection. You will need to check that the data is stored properly in the source database. This isn't as easy as it sounds and just because it's showing correctly in whatever client tool you are using doesn't mean it's correct either. You should check that the hex value is correct for UTF-8 encoding of one of the values in your source database. If that is correct, check it in the destination database. What client application are you using to view the data? MySQL server can store data in a different character set than is return

Comment: @JessBalint Interesting! I am not sure if I did it right, when converting a city name manually like this: *SELECT HEX(CONVERT('Алханай' USING utf8))* it gave the same result as when selecting it from the city table – is that proof that the data is stored correctly? The values from the target DB are the same as from the source DB, except the russian names which are all 3F3F...because of the ???? .. But then I saw something else: when I do *SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';* the "character_set_database' is *latin1* and "character_set_results" is empty – could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @altsyset: yes, I tried that before with several DB-clients. Like PHPMyAdmin or MySQL-Workbench but it either took more than an hour (big database) or the result was missing a few rows – I don't know why, I never had any problems with MySQL-Workbench. But since I have to alter some tables anyways, I thought I do it on the fly while copying the data myself.

Comment: You can find the UTF-8 encoding of the first character of that string here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0430/index.htm. is it showing the right value? The result should be 28 chars long in hex representation, which is 14 bytes in UTF-8 encoding. What client program are you using? The character_set_results is used to tell the server what character encoding you want the results sent back in. If it's blank, their stored encoding is used.

Comment: Found the problem! After checking the HEX-values with the page you gave me, I realized that the source db has all values stored correctly – so does the target server (technically). So it had to do with the JDBC-driver settings I was using to read / write the data and it did! `setProperty("useCompression", "true");` thats the reason. I just removed that line and everything is working now :)  Thank you for all your help – I learned some interesting things today!

Comment: It would be great if you tell me what application you are using to read/write data. The compressed protocol should never change the data! If there's a bug that you can help narrow down, other users will benefit. Thanks.